# How to take just the text element from word2vec similar word list? python

Tags: python, list, word2vec

I have this code and the result I am searching for is an array with just the words from the most similar list.

```
model1.most_similar('Mercedes-Benz SLK-Class')[:5]
[('BMW M4', 0.9959905743598938),
 ('Maserati Coupe', 0.9949707984924316),
 ('Porsche Cayman', 0.9945154190063477),
 ('Mercedes-Benz SLS AMG GT', 0.9944609999656677),
 ('Maserati Spyder', 0.9942780137062073)]
```

the list example is as follows:

```
print(array)
['BMW M4','Maserati Coupe','Porsche Cayman','Mercedes-Benz SLS AMG GT','Maserati Spyder']
```

thank you for your help :))

Comment: `words = [i[0] for i in model1.most_similar('Mercedes-Benz SLK-Class')]`?

Answer (score 1):

A simple Python 'list comprehension' is a good way to perform simple transformations on a list, such as modifying/filtering each item into a new list.

This would do the trick (but see below for an even more vivid approach):

```
sims = wordvecs_model.most_similar('Mercedes-Benz SLK-Class', topn=5)
sims_tokens = [item[0] for item in sims]
```

You can use 'structured unpacking' of each tuple into meaningful temporary variables to be even more explicit about what's happening, as for example:

```
sims = wordvecs_model.most_similar('Mercedes-Benz SLK-Class', topn=5)
sims_tokens [token for token, similarity in sims]
```